# Tensorflow empty model.ckpt

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I try to design my own model detector on tensorflow with objectdetector API.

I run the *running pet* example, but it tells me this:

> To speed up the training process, it is recommended that users re-use the feature extractor parameters from a pre-existing object classification or detection checkpoint. train_config provides two fields to specify pre-existing checkpoints: fine_tune_checkpoint and from_detection_checkpoint. fine_tune_checkpoint should provide a path to the pre-existing checkpoint (ie:"/usr/home/username/checkpoint/model.ckpt-#####")

Is it possible not to indicate the fine_tune_checkpoint and the model.ckcp, or to get an empty model?

Edit: I just notice that the model.ckpt is used in object_detection algorithm. How can I do my own model.cfpt?

Answer (score 0):

Model checkpoints are creating automatically time by time, while training the model or when the frozen interference graph is exported from the model checkpoints. The training process is described pretty well [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md).
It is also stricktly recommended to use fine-tune checkpoints ([here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) are some of them) even if you're training the model on your own dataset, because training process on a powerful GPU without checkpoints can last few days.